# Add GTKmm to CodeBlocks - Windows

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, gtkmm

Codeblocks can't find the instalation of GTKmm. I instaled it on the default path: "C:\gtkmm"

I have tried many things like adding `"pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags"` and `"pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs"` but i still get:

```
"fatal error: gtkmm.h: No such file or directory"
```

What can i do?

My setup is Codeblocks with MinGW on windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working on Windows 8

1. Made sure the gtkmm version in the pkg-config command is correct - mine is 2.4 (checked in lib folder in gtkmm64 installation folder)
2. Under Settings > Compile > Toolchain executables, made sure that the compilers installation directory is C:\Codeblocks\MinGW (I installed Code 13.12 with WinGW included)
3. Under Settings > Environment > Environment variables, then click Add:
   Variable name: PKG_CONFIG_PATH
   Variable value: C:\gtkmm64\lib\pkgconfig

(I installed Codeblocks and gtkmm64 under C:\ to avoid the space in "Program Files" which some things dont seem to like)